# How to access CSS variables created in a scoped style block in Vue + Buefy

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, buefy

By following the [Buefy documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/customization/), I was able to customize my colors and even create new ones, using as `is-[colorName]` as a class of HTML elements.

```
<style lang="scss">
    // Import Bulma's core
    @import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";

    //Create your own colors.
    $download: #253091;
    $download-inverted: findColorInvert($download);

    // Setup $colors to use as bulma classes (e.g. 'is-twitter')
    $colors: (
      "white": ($white, $black),
      "black": ($black, $white),
      "light": ($light, $light-invert),
      "dark": ($dark, $dark-invert),
      "primary": ($primary, $primary-invert),
      "info": ($info, $info-invert),
      "success": ($success, $success-invert),
      "warning": ($warning, $warning-invert),
      "danger": ($danger, $danger-invert),

      "download": ($download, $download-inverted),
    );

    // Import Bulma and Buefy styles
    @import "~bulma";
    @import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";

    //Custom global styles.    
    #app {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
</style>
```

Now, in a page, I need to access a color variable, for example $download to create a simple gradient.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";

    .gradient {
        background-image: linear-gradient($download, #info);
    }
</style>
```

How can I access the variables in another Vue component/page?

I tought that since the App.vue style block was not scoped, I could access the newly created variables from everywhere, but apparently, I can't.

Comment: import them in each page that you need, or create a main `app.scss` file and import it there. then import the `app.scss` file in your `main.js` file. either way, webpack won't bundle n+1 times, just once.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by "importing in each page that I need", how would I do that? 

For example, I want to use two variables, one created by me `$download` and other that I could alter the value, but that was created by bulma, such as `$light`.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS variables are attached to the #app container:

```
#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

**Option 1:**
Some Buefy elements are launched outside of your app container. For instance, the Buefy Snackbar. You can attach it to this container by passing in '#app' into the container perimeter, which would then put your CSS variables within its scope:

```
  this.$buefy.snackbar.open({
    message: '...',
    container: '#app',
  })
```

**Option 2:** If your Buefy element can receive a custom class, you might want to define a global class with your override and pass that class in as a parameter to your element.